# Use An Aggregate With Computed Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, computed-column

I am wanting to alter my table to have a column that is the SUM() of two other fields.  I have this syntax

```
ALTER TABLE SalesData
ADD AC AS SUM(COALESCE(val1,0)+COALESCE(val2,0))
```

However it produces an error of

> An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint.

What is the proper way to add a field and set the fields value to a calculation?

Comment: You cannot use a SUM aggregation on a computer column because the computed column acts on each and every row. Aggregations use multiple rows to perform an operation, so when you think about it, aggregating doesn't make much sense at the "row" level. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not use SUM() for this.  Just code

> ALTER TABLE .. ADD .. AS (col1 + col2);

(see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table )